# Importing gdal_array from gdal in Conda

Tags: python, gdal, array

I'm working through python examples in a geospatial book using jupyter notebook and have run into trouble trying to import gdal_array from my gdal installation.  I've seen several old questions and answers that supposedly fix this with a series of conda uninstalls and re-installs but following the answers gets me nowhere.  I'm running on windows 10 and 64 bit if that makes a difference.  I'm also in Python 3.7 and gdal version 2.3.3.  I've already uninstalled gdal and it's dependencies (numpy etc.) and reinstalled but to no avail.

All the examples use gdal_array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume these examples involve using `gdal_array` to directly read a geospatial file into a numpy array from the filepath.

```py
from osgeo import gdal_array

# read raster filepath
rasterArray = gdal_array.LoadFile("/path/to/file")
```

You can interchange these with the more current handling of files by creating a GDAL dataset first and then using `ReadAsArray()`.

```py
ds = gdal.Open("/path/to/file")
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arr = band.ReadAsArray()
```