# Multiple methods syntax

Tags: python, geocoding, syntax, documentation

I am new in Python and learning to use it for spatial processing. I bought the book "Learning Spatial Analysis with Python". In the book, I often see syntaxes with multiple methods (a=module.method.method/module.method/module) that seem to be inherited such as:

```
Example 1:

a = gdal_array.numpy.fromstring(i.tobytes(),'b')

a.shape = i.im.size[1], i.im.size[0]

Example 2:

ndvi = gd.loadfile(source).astype(gd.numpy.uint8)
```

I try to understand this syntax, but I cannot get a grip on this with the documentation I find on the internet. I do not have to know explicitly the above mentioned examples, but try to figure out in what 'think direction' I have to find the solution to be able to read and understand these syntaxes. Are these just methods inside methods?

Comment: Your issue seems to be more a fundamental Python issue than a GIS-centric one. It doesn't reflect well on the author/editor that the method chaining style used is not explained or introduced somewhere, but it's not uncommon in real code (and sometimes used too extensively on a readability basis).

Comment: Duplicate of [Importing gdal_array from gdal in Conda](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341541/2581)

Comment: Your edit reinforces the idea that this is not a GIS issue. Python does not support "methods inside methods." This is just basic data chaining -- methods which return results which support methods, e.g., `"one 2 three".split()[-1].upper()` is a common way to extract the uppercase of the last term in a parsable string, but  `"one 2 three".upper().split()[-1]` would also work, while  `"one 2 three".split().upper()[-1]` would not (since `str.split()` returns a `list` of `str` not a `str` and therefore does not support `upper()`)

Comment: Thanks! That was the explanation that I needed. I was now able to reconstruct it in the documentation I found. I was thinking too difficult.

Comment: You also need to have a look to "how modules were imported", e.g. `import foo` vs `import foo as bar` vs `from foo import sub` vs `from foo import sub.qux.method_a as foo_method_a`. From your example, we cannot know what `gd` actually is. You should then update your post to include such pieces of knowledge so that other could help you the best that they can.